# Index "Lazy Loading" images in Bing and Baidu

Tags: seo, bing, yahoo, image-search, baidu

I read this questions:

- [Lazy loading images and effects on SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/61761/19975)
- [Is this a good approach to image Lazy Loading for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/26190/19975)

The responses make it clear that there LazyLoad works well in google, but I wonder if this is valid for *Bing bot* (Yahoo bot) and *Baidu bot* also.

I looked for documentation on the subject, but have not found anything about it.

How bots of them work with *Lazy Loading*?

Comment: I've written many of the answers to those questions.  For my sites, Google image search has always been the only game in town.   The amount of traffic available from Bing and Baidu image search has been tiny.   I've never looked into optimizing for their image search, it just isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Stephen's comment, **[Baidu is little bit insecure.](https://citizenlab.org/2016/02/privacy-security-issues-baidu-browser/)**

As SEO concerned, just do everything as you are doing with google and it'll all be fine. Amount of traffic that Baidu and Bing provide versus amount of traffic that google provides is best explained in this picture below.

For December 2012, the search landscape was like this:

[image]

- Google: 114.7 billion searches, 65.2% share
- Baidu: 14.5 billion searches, 8.2% share
- Yahoo: 8.6 billion searches, 4.9% share
- Yandex: 4.8 billion searches, 2.8% share
- Microsoft: 4.5 billion searches, 2.5% share
- Others: 28.7 billion searches, 16.3% share