# Does google index lazy-loaded images?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, lazyloading

I am using React and the library `react-lazy-load-image-component`

I do show LazyImages on top of the page but I notice that google is not indexing most of those images.

They do index them sometime, but other times not so I am confused.

In my use case I have only one "Post/Article" with the image on top (lazy-loaded) and below the title and the article content.

My React code is very simple

```
<LazyImage
                            className={'img-responsive'}
                            style={img.style}
                            src={img.src}
                            alt={img.alt}
                            placeholderSrc={
                                'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=='
                            }
                        />
```

The html coming from the server is

```
<span class=" lazy-load-image-background "
      style="background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==);background-size:100% 100%;display:inline-block"><span
        class="img-responsive" style="display:inline-block"></span></span></a></p>
<h1>Article title</h1>
<p>First paragraph of the article</p>
```

That does not seem seo friendly to me. I believe this library need to include data-src or something like that in the server-side rendered content as well for the search engines to wait and index the images.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: [Lazy loading images and effects on SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61761/lazy-loading-images-and-effects-on-seo) which is mostly focused on web results, but also asks about indexing the images themselves.

Comment: [Is this a good approach to image Lazy Loading for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26190/is-this-a-good-approach-to-image-lazy-loading-for-seo) for a way to lazy-load and have images indexed